# Custom UITableViewCell showing incorrect values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController displaying custom cells with a few labels and a custom UIView. In the tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) method it seems that the colors are not being reset when the cells are reused (they appear completely random). How can I fix this?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let historyEntry = allHistoryEntries[indexPath.section].histories![indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HistoryCell

    cell.dateLabel.text = "\(getDayFrom(date: (historyEntry.beginDate)!))"

    let highestBac = getHighestBac(history: historyEntry)
    cell.highestBacLabel.text = "Høyeste promille " + String(describing: Double(highestBac).roundTo(places: 2))

    cell.costLabel.text = String(describing: getNorwegianDayFrom(date: (historyEntry.beginDate!))) + " brukte du " + String(describing: calculateTotalCostBy(history: historyEntry)) + ",-"

    let goal = Double(AppDelegate.getUserData()?.goalPromille ?? 0.0)
    let red = UIColor(red: 193/255.0, green: 26/255.0, blue: 26/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let green = UIColor(red:26/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 73/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    let color = highestBac > goal ? red : green

    cell.highestBacLabel.textColor = color
    cell.circleView.ringColor = color

    return cell
}
```

Here is an image showing the colors. The expected behavior is that red OR green color should be used, not a combination.

**UPDATE:**
It is only the ringColor showing the wrong color.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "when the cells are reused"?  How are you reusing them?

Comment: I might be wrong, but from what I understand cells are reused when they no longer appear on the screen, e.g if there are more cells that can fit in the screen. So it was my suspicion that the cells were reused when the tableview was scrolled, maintaining the colors that were set originally.

Comment: Is it the case that the `textColor` is changing correctly, but the `circleView.ringColor` is sometimes incorrect?  (This is what the picture appears to show, I'm just asking if this behavior is consistent)

Comment: I didn't notice that, but yes it appears so! The behavior is consistent that way.

Comment: What is this `circleView` and `ringColor` by the way?  Is it a `UIView` and a `borderColor`? or Something else?  How is the color being set on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be a lack of calling `setNeedsDisplay()` in my CircleView class. Thanks William GP.

Answer (score 2):

if there is no default color, reset the color to clear with `prepareForReuse()`. This function must be inside your `HistoryCell` class

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() 
    //Reset label to clear color
    self.highestBacLabel.textColor = UIColor.clear
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reset some value, such as `textColor` when a cell is being dequeued for reuse you can override the `prepareForReuse` method in the `UITableViewCell` subclass (HistoryCell) like so:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse() 
    //Reset label color back to default green
    let green = UIColor(red:26/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 73/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.highestBacLabel.textColor = green
}
```

Comment: I updated my question to be more specific. There is no default color as the colors is determined by highestBac > goal. The colors simply appear random when scrolling.

Comment: @SimenFonnes Can you show the code for your `getHighestBac` and your `AppDelegate.getUserData()` functions?  I'm guessing you've got some issue there.  At first glance, why not just get a single reference to `getUserData().goalPromille`, perhaps in `viewDidLoad` so that you don't have to keep going back to AppDelegate and calling that function for every cell?